# How to fix "cannot access file because it is being used by another process"

Tags: java

I'm running a program that will call a code based on a condition.

```
    if (charCount >= 152) {
        new InformixToPDF().createPdflandscape( DESTINATION + 
                "\\" + new_file_name + "_" + df.format(new Date()) + ".pdf",source);            
        }
    //function to call for portrait conversion
    else {
        new InformixToPDF().createPdfportrait( DESTINATION + 
                "\\" + new_file_name + "_" + df.format(new Date()) + ".pdf",source);
         }
```

Here the code that's called if else condition are met.

```
  public void createPdfportrait(String dest,String source) throws DocumentException, IOException {
   File myfile = new File(source);
   Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);

   document.setMargins (20, 0, 50, 80); 
   PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
   document.open();

   br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(source));
   String line;
   Paragraph p;

   //PDF font configuration
   Font normal = new Font(FontFamily.COURIER, 7);
   Font bold = new Font(FontFamily.COURIER, 7, Font.BOLD);

   //add page into PDF
   boolean title = true;
       while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
       p = new Paragraph(line.length() == 0 ? " ": line, title ? bold : normal);
       document.add(p);
       }
       document.close();

       System.out.println("Informix4gl report file " + source + " has been converted to PDF");
       Path sourcePath = Paths.get(source);
       Path destinationPath = Paths.get(MOVE);
       try {
           Files.move(sourcePath, destinationPath,
                   StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
```

After conversion has been done the current file. it need to be move to another folder using this code where "source" is the current file and "MOVE" is destination folder.

```
   Path sourcePath = Paths.get(source);
   Path destinationPath = Paths.get(MOVE);
   try {
       Files.move(sourcePath, destinationPath,
               StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
   } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

The codes is executed and pdf is created successfully but error "java.nio.file.FileSystemException: O:\xx\yy\zz\test -> O:\xx\yy\zz\FOLDER C: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process." appear.

How do I fix this and what change should I make to the code to avoid this error?

I know these question was asked a lot but none of that fixed my problem. However I may have missed some.

Comment: Which line in the code throws the exception? you can debug that.

Comment: Can you post a _full traceback_? It will be helpful.

Comment: According to what you posted, the error message means that file `O:\xx\yy\zz\FOLDER` is open either by your java program or by some other program. Also `O:\xx\yy\zz\test\` looks like the path to a folder and not to a file. Are you trying to move a single file or an entire folder?

Comment: I'm trying move a single file. Sorry there was an extra " \ ".

Comment: STRONG SUGGESTION: Add `Thread.sleep(5000);` (or something similar) after `document.close()`, and see if that helps.  Perhaps IText isn't "closing" the file immediately, so your nio.move() is getting a "file in use" error if it tries immediately afterward.

Comment: I don't see in the code you posted that you close the source file. If you are trying to move that file when you haven't closed it, that would explain your error.

Comment: You need to close the `FileReader` (which you don't have a variable pointed to).  Closing `br` the `BufferedReader` may be enough, but maybe you need to get a variable pointing to the `FileReader` and close that too.

Comment: @Abra how do I close the source file?

Comment: A quick and dirty fix would be to add `br.close();` after the line `document.close();` in method `createPdfportrait()` in the code you posted.

Comment: @Abra already did that, still the same.